# Rush Webservice Conflict in Class Values

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, stored-procedures, asynchronous

I have a web service that calls a method asynchronously:

```
   public Response Method1(Request request)
        {
            new StaticClass.ProcessAsync(request);

            return new Response
            {
                result = 0,
                resultDescription = "success"
            };

        }
```

Inside the method `ProcessAsync(Request request)` I am selecting from a database :

- a connectionstring
- a stored procedure name

  and executing that stored procedure.

The value of the connection string and stored procedure vary depending on the Request class values:

```
Settings settings = GetInfoFromDatabase(request);
string conString = settings.ConnectionsString;
string storedProcedureName = settings.StoredProcedureName;
//execute stored procedure
```

When there is a rush of requests on that web service, I am getting the following error a lot :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'storedprocedurename'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

What could be the problem? Could it be a conflict in values of Settings class due to rush?

Comment: Please provide full code of `StaticClass.ProcessAsync()` and `GetInfoFromDatabase()` method. It seems like concurrency issue but there is no way to figure it out w/o looking at the code. And why do you use `new` keyword? is ProcessAsync a class and you calling the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem in your database connection code while accessing database multiple times in a short period. Why dont you try EF to connect and execute SP. It's simple and can handle so much requests easily.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that when there is a rush , one of the user is not having rights to the database either at read level or execution level.

Try to see if SQL Server log files help.